# Fail project/build when non-default branch fails

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We use TeamCity and we would like to be visually alerted that we broke a build in a sub/feature-branch.

TeamCity for some odd reason does not support failing (coloring it red) the project or build when a non default branch fails. There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23414#u=1467027048061) on the TeamCity YouTrack for this, but it doesn't contain a workaround.

I was hoping someone here has implemented a solution or workaround to be able to use the project overview to alert us if a build is failing in a sub/feature branch.

[image]

How do you make the TeamCity project overview arrows red when a non-default branch fails?